# What is the pros and cons of using connection pool and just one connection?

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

Generally, when you develop a client application which will communicate the Server (Such as MySQL, redis-server, etc), there are 2 options:

1) Using connection pool: That is the application will create some connections after initialization. Then when there is a request, the application will select a connection from the pool, and use it to send the request. (E.g, unixodbc);

2) Use only one connection to send all requests.

I have searched many times, but unfortunately, I can't get any valuable comparisons about the 2 methods. So could anyone give some comments on them? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is a method that stores open connections in a "pool" instead of establishing a new connection for each database query.

Connection pooling holds the pipe open for data transmission so others don't have to establish their own pipes. It's essentially a shared connection to the database.

Comment: One connection can also be kept open.

Answer (score 0):

Your options aren't mutually exclusive. You can use a connection pool and still only use one connection as far as the application is concerned. The advantage of that is that if the connection breaks while idle in the pool, the pool won't return it but will create a new one.